# telnet non interactive: connection closed by foreign host

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp, connection, telnet

if I do

```
telnet host_ip port < /dev/null
Trying host_ip...
Connected to host_ip.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

By checking the wireshark, the client side sends `tcp rst` to the host side. Can anyone explain what happens exactly? Does telnet requires interactive mode?

Comment: what use would there be for a telnet session with standard input closed?

Comment: well, get or redirect the output from the terminal server via telnet

Comment: what terminal? you closed the terminal (that is typically attached via standard input)

Comment: try yourself, it is easy to reproduce. "terminal server" is usually the console server to connecting rs-232 for embedded devices. google "terminal server", you have better idea. here we want to redirect the terminal server output via telnet.

Comment: you're not redirecting output, you're closing standard input. why are you closing standard input?

Comment: i am naming a use case that you are asking. and it makes sense that this use case does not require input.

Comment: well if you break the terminal then you're going to have to fake a terminal (see meuh's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that TelNet service is running on linux machine? try this one

```
telnet localhost 23 (23 port of telnet)
```

or try to use [netcat](http://www.terminalinflection.com/use-netcat-not-telnet-to-test-network-connectivity/)

Comment: yes, if I run without closing the stdin (i.e. telnet ip port), it works fine. if you try, you will find it like this as well. i just do not know much about telnet, and need some details.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is bidirectional, so when one end closes, it prompts the other end to close too. If you want to keep stdin open at the client you can use tools like `expect` to wrap the call inside a pty:

```
expect <<\!
spawn telnet host port
expect eof
!
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to see the ubuntu system log with this command

**sudo gedit /var/log/syslog**

and if you will see this error "execv( /usr/sbin/tcpd ) failed: No such file or directory" then run this command

**sudo apt-get install tcpd**

it will solve your problem (if not then you need to search your system error on google)